# Complexity of calculating $f^{(n)}(0)$/extracting a coefficient of a functions taylor-series

Tags: computational-complexity, generating-functions, taylor-series

Many combinatorial problems can be solved using generating functions.

In such a case, we  obtain a function $f(x)$, which (for usual) has a taylor-expansion:
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n\ge 0 } a_n x^n 
$$
So that the coefficients $a_n$ are exactly the elements of the sequence we're looking for.

Further, we may assume that the function $f(x)$ is given in closed form, i.e. as a finite function built using only [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function).

Now, unlike when we want to determine the Taylor-expansion, we now want a single coefficient $a_k$, for some fixed $k$.

What's the most efficient method to do this?

---

Addendum:

I've asked the question before on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3313001), where I've gotten an answer that a bound of $\mathcal O(log_2(n)^\alpha) $ is possible. However, I can't figure out from the answer how that bound is established.

Comment: Here $n=k$ (i.e. the index you want), and $\alpha$ must depend on the specific function.  But some caution must be required in interpreting this bound: e.g. for the exponential function you are computing $1/n!$, and $n!$ has nearly $n \log n$ digits.

Comment: Do you want the exact coefficient, or do you want a numerically good approximation?

Comment: @BrendanMcKay Whatever is fastest, as long as the approximation comes with an error bound.